# Ansible script to copy file based on date

Tags: ansible

I have created below playbook to archive log files on remote server. The script perform based on the key work in the host file.

```
tasks:
 - name: Create a tar.gz archive of log files.
   archive:
     path:
        - "{{item.path}}"
     dest: "{{item.dest}}"
     format: gz
     force_archive: yes
     owner: ubuntu
   become: true
   when: "inventory_hostname is search(item.key)"
   with_items: 
       - {path: "/var/log/grafana/grafana.log", dest: "/tmp/grafana.log.gz", key: "grafana"}
```

Is it possible to archive the files based on a date variable. For example, if I pass the date 11-11-2020 at the time of execution, then the script has to archive only the file created at this date?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [`find:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html) task and its [returned `files` list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#return-files)? You will have to filter based on whether you mean `ctime` or `mtime`, but [those are available to you](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html#return-stat/mtime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a var with all log files.
- Use `stat` module to retrieve facts for files, this module reaturns `ctime` value wich is `Time of last metadata update or creation (depends on OS)` and register the return values on a variable.
- In `archive` task use `wiht_nested` with `files` and `file_data` with a when condition where validate the items of both are the same and the `ctime` is equal to a `date` variable.
- Execute playbook sending `date` variable as `extra-vars`.

`playbook.yml`

```yaml
- name: Archive files
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
    
  vars:
    files:
      - {path: "/home/vagrant/l1.txt", dest: "/tmp/grafana.log.gz", key: "grafana"}
      - {path: "/home/vagrant/l2.txt", dest: "/tmp/grafana.log.gz", key: "grafana"}
      - {path: "/etc/host.conf", dest: "/tmp/grafana.log.gz", key: "grafana"}
    
  tasks:
  - name: Get file data
    stat:
      path: "{{ item.path }}"
    with_items: "{{ files }}"
    register: file_data
    
  - name: Create a tar.gz archive of log files.
    archive:
      path: "{{item[0].path}}"
      dest: "{{item[0].dest}}"
      format: gz
      force_archive: yes
      owner: ubuntu
    become: true
    when: "inventory_hostname is search(item[0].key) and item[0].path == item[1].stat.path and  '%d-%m-%Y' | strftime(item[1].stat.ctime) == {{ date }}"
    with_nested:
      - "{{ files }}"
      - "{{ file_data.results }}"
```

Execute playbook

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory -e "date='11-11-2020'"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary for the help. I am getting a syntax error near 'when' condition. The offending line appears to be:

    become: true
    when: "inventory_hostname is search(item.key)" and item[0].path == item[1].stat.path and  '%d-%m-%Y' | strftime(item[1].stat.ctime) == {{ date }}
                                                   ^ here
I tried modifying it multiple time but still no luck.

Comment: fatal: [vm]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional .......... The error was: error while evaluating conditional (inventory_hostname is search(item.key) and item[0].path == item[1].stat.path and  '%d-%m-%Y' | strftime(item[1].stat.ctime) == {{ date }}): 'list object' has no attribute 'key'\n\nThe error appears to be in 'new.yml': line 16, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Create a tar.gz

Comment: my mistake, its inventory_hostname is search(item[0]), I just edited my answer. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I think the inverted comma should be at the end? when: "inventory_hostname is search(item[0].key)  and item[0].path == item[1].stat.path and  '%d-%m-%Y' | strftime(item[1].stat.ctime) == {{ date }}", also is it possible to check the files in a directory instead passing all files?

Comment: Gary, any suggestion to find out the files from a directory based on the date? thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks @Wonderhost I've just edited my answer. You could use find module to find all files in a directory and register all files and stat task use that variable to get the information of each file.

Comment: @Techiescorner you need to use find module to get all files of directory and in the stat task compare the date of each files with the date you want. if you want, write a question in stackoverflow and write here the link, I'll help you gladly.